# Erro com Ajax quando coloco no servidor

Tags: jquery, ajax, servidor

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com uma dificuldade, quando estou usando meu código no meu banco local, ele funciona normalmente... Quando eu jogo no servidor, ele da o seguinte erro:
DataTables warning: table id=dt_cliente - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Já fiz e refiz de tudo, entrei pelo link do erro, e fui seguindo o passo a passo.
e chega até aqui
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembrando que, no meu banco local ele funciona, e quando abro pelo servidor, ele da esse erro logo de cara, sem efetuar nenhum procedimento..
O que eu posso fazer pra resolver?
Ficarei muito grato caso me ajudem..
Algumas informações já estão nos comentários, mas por recomendação do Leandro, irei postar elas aqui.

Informações úteis que possam ajudar:
Importei o  banco local EXATAMENTE IGUAL para o server.
Antes eu tentei apenas MOSTRAR os dados, e aparecia normal, depois que implementei a função de adicionar/editar as tabelas ele mostrou o erro mencionado.

Segundo o erro, acontece no listar.php
 que tem o seguinte código `

```
include ("conexion.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE estado = 1 ORDER BY idusuario desc;";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

if( !$resultado ){ 
    die("Error");
}else{ 
    $array["data"] = []; //devuelve un arreglo vacío por si no hay registros en la base de datos.
    while( $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($resultado)){ 
        $arreglo["data"][] = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);

    }
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);`
```

E esse é o do meu "conexion.php"

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "*****";
$password = "****";
$bd = "*****";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $bd);
if (!$conexion){ 
    die('Error de Conexión: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());    
}   
?>
```

Tenho quase certeza que é algo no servidor, pois já existem alguns códigos funcionando, o que percebi é que eles são apenas "mysql" e o que coloquei agora, é "mysqli". Não sei se pode ser algo do tipo...

Lembrando que, no localhost eu consigo adicionar/remover/editar normalmente, o banco funciona 100%, quando eu jogo pro servidor pelo winscp, ( mesmo nome do banco,arquivos, pastas, usuarios, etc) ele não carrega nem as informações.

Caso necessário, posso passar o código todo compactado, pois tem algumas pastas de dependencia, tipo js,css etc... ( que também inclui no server).
Assim podemos testar se é algum erro REALMENTE no servidor, ou no código em sí.
** Aliás, o servidor fica hospedado em uma máquina local, que acesso pelo IP, 
ou seja eu digito o ip 177.xxx.xxx.xx / pasta quando estou fora da rede, mas meus arquivos são hospedados nela, então o banco é o localhost mesmo..
Não sei se fui claro ou consegui explicar o que queria...

Comment: Conferiu se a estrutura do banco está igual nos dois ambientes? Erro 500 não é relacionado ao Ajax, é um erro de execução do seu código no lado do servidor.

Comment: Boa tarde Leandro, sim, eu importei do meu banco local, e coloquei exatamente no servidor... o que pode estar acontecendo, é talvez o Usuário não esteja como ROOT, ou algo assim? ( eu coloquel all previleges nele).. Outra coisa, quando os dados eram apenas MOSTRADOS estava funcionando, porém quando implementei o AJAX na hora de Cadastrar/editar as coisas, ele da esse erro

Comment: mostre o código

Comment: Esse é o código do "listar.php" que é onde mostra o erro.. http://prntscr.com/nk1r74

Outra coisa que percebi é, no meu código eu uso "mysqli" porém nos códigos que já tem funcionando no banco, é usando apenas "mysql".
Porém mesmo eu trocando somente para Mysql ele não funciona :(
Não sei se essa informação ajuda xD
E esse é o conexion.php 
http://prntscr.com/nk1tcj

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que é alguma configuração no servidor (Não faço ideia de como efetuar, ou corrigir isso)..
O que posso fazer, ( também não sei se é permitido) é compactar todo o código, incluindo o db, e postar aqui para testes, caso funcione, tenho a certeza que é REALMENTE algo no servidor, ai talvez facilite na hora de solucionar...
Não me importo quanto ao código, apenas gostaria de solucionar a dificuldade e deixar funcionando xD

Comment: Evite o uso de imagens e inclua as informações em sua pergunta, não nos comentários. Eu , por exemplo, não consigo nem ver os dois prints por bloqueio na infra da empresa.

Comment: opa, me desculpe Leandro, irei editar a pergunta incluindo os dados, e postar o código direto, e não o print dele.. Só um minuto

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver... Alguém tem alguma dica na qual eu possa seguir/tentar?
Ou alguma outra forma de pesquisar sobre o erro por favor

Comment: Sem ver o stack do erro 500 não tem como ajudar

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta, mas como posso ver o stack do erro 500?
Vi que em um host, podemos acessar o site etc, mas se é local como posso fazer?

Comment: O que aparece se você faz a requisição direto, sem o ajax, que aliás, você não apresentou até agora

Answer (score 0):

Como imaginei, o problema era o servidor que não rodava meus códigos por algum motivo, fiz um servidor interno, deixei ele público e deu certo, ( Não sei como fecha o tópico xD)

REsolvido